# Subkeys of multiple generated sets not combineable Shamir Secret Sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

I am using a Shamir Secret Sharing implementation in Java and I have the use case,
that I may have to generate more Subkeys of the Secret after I already generated some.
Generating them works, but if I combine the new keys with the old keys I can't recreate the secret.

I am using GF(256) as finite field.

For example:

1. Generate some subkeys (Set 1) (k=2, n=3)
2. Generate more subkeys (Set 2) (k=2, n=3)
3. Combine key 1 from Set 1 with key 2 from Set 2 -> Won't recreate Master

Is that a fault in the implementation or is it meant to be this way?

Comment: When you "generate more subkeys', what are you doing to ensure that those are based on the same secret polynomial that the first set of subkeys used?